# Best practice when loading data for a view on a background thread without lag

Tags: android, android-asynctask

An Android application has two activities.

Activity A shows a list of items.
Activity B shows some details about a particular item.

The details are loaded from a largish SQLite database. The queries used to generate the data take about 250 to 500milliseconds on a reasonable phone.

My question is what is the best practice for loading the data while providing a nice user experience.

Currently Activity B executes an AsyncTask when it's created. When the task completes it creates a number of views and adds them to the screen. No data is loaded on the UI thread.

To the user Activity B opens with the nice standard zoom animation and then a fraction of a second later the view populates with data. It looks a little crap IMO.

Another option is to load the data on the UI thread. If I do this at the right time then the screen freezes with the list item selected for 250ms while the data loads and then the view changes with the standard zoom animation but it's zooming into an already populated view. It looks a lot nicer but I am blocking the UI thread which is not ideal.

What is the best way to achieve a nice transition when the new view isn't ready yet?

Comment: Put a progress dialog on top of Activity A while loading data, add cancel possibility, plus most importantly, do loading in separate Thread. As this is network operation you should never rely on receiving response and leave user possibility to cancel operation easily. IMHO that is.

Comment: It's not a network operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put a `progress dialog` for loading data task and if you don't then..

You can use `onProgressUpdate()` method of your `AsyncTask` for intervally update your resulted data from database to UI..

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
        //this runs in UI thread so its safe to modify the UI 
        myTextField.append("finished call " + progress); 
    }
```

`•onProgressUpdate` – called whenever publishProgress is called from the background task, used to report progress back to the UI.

Also you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clause of `sqlite database` for fetching data from database with bound number of returned result in your `select query` for fetching large amount of data from database..

Example:

```
Select * from Animals LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a really good idea in my use case. The most important part of the screen loads very quickly.

Comment: Welcome back & +1 for a nice answer.

Comment: @user370305 Yeah I was searching for you from many days. I would like you to pay a visit in some rooms to have a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat).